# Can you control which display a window created by Javascript is displayed on?

Tags: javascript

My PC has more than one display attached.  I'm working on a web app that displays data in a table in the browser.  When the user clicks on a row of the table, a window with details about the row selected is displayed.  If the user clicks on a different row, a new window opens.

I have two requirements I need to make work:

1. The windows should not stack up one on top of the other, they should cascade.  I've got code that works for Firefox, but IE and Chrome just open each window in the same place so they stack up.  If I keep track of the number of windows opened, I can finagle a cascading mechanism, but is there a better way?
2. If the machine has multiple displays, it'd be nice if the window with the table were on one screen and the details windows opened on the other.  I haven't been able to find anything in any of the searches I've done.  Is there some code somewhere that does this?

Edit:

For @Neal:

```
Function newWin( mypage, myname, cascade ) {
            if (!cascade) cascade = false;

    if (!myname)
            myname = 'DETAILS';

    var w = 820;
    var h = 685;
    var settings = 'height=' + h + ',';
    settings += 'width=' + w + ',';

    if (!cascade) {
        if (screen.width) {
            var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
            var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
        }
        else {
            winl = 0;
            wint = 0;
        }
        if (winl < 0) winl = 0;
        if (wint < 0) wint = 0;

        settings += 'top=' + wint + ',';
        settings += 'left=' + winl + ',';
    }

    settings += 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes';
    gPopupWindow = window.open(mypage, myname, settings);

    // fix for IE focus
    // when from ajax loaded list
    // see convoy dropdownlist item click
    //gPopupWindow.focus();
    setTimeout(function () { gPopupWindow.focus() }, 0);
}
```

By passing true for `cascade`, Firefox lets the OS open the window where it wants.  But IE & Chrome always put the window in the same place, though where it goes on the screen is different for each browser.  I was hoping that IE & Chrome would act like Firefox does, but browser differences is a fact of life.

As I said, I can keep track of how many windows have been opened by calling this function and compute new left & top coordinates based on that number. I'd rather not, though.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that there's no way to control on which screen a new window will be displayed on a multi-screen system from JavaScript.  Not without writing your own DLL and incorporating it into your application.  There are ways to call functions in DLLs, but it's not worth it, as the DLL would be Windows specific and you'd need to do something else on the Mac & Linux.

Further, different browsers complicate this problem, as the method to add custom code differs from browser to browser, as well.

For that matter, if you don't specify the left & top coordinates when displaying a new window, each browser displays the new window in a different place on whatever screen it decides to display the window on.  The behavior is completely inconsistent browser to browser, let alone OS to OS.

Don't do it.